# Chef download and install Oracle Java on Windows

Tags: java, chef-infra, silent-installer

I want to install Java with Chef 13 on Windows 7.

Installing from file is easy, but I want also to download it from Oracle archives. The thing is, Oracle requires special cookie - `oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie`.

I've tried [java](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/java#readme) cookbook, as it seems people did it without problems. Hovewer, after running Chef I get error:

```
Recipe: java::notify
  * log[jdk-version-changed] action nothing (skipped due to action :nothing)
Recipe: java::windows
  * ruby_block[Enable Accessing cookies] action run
    - execute the ruby block Enable Accessing cookies
  * remote_file[C:/Users/User\.chef\local-mode-cache\cache/jdk-7u79-windows-i586.exe] action create[2017-05-25T08:30:21+02:00] WARN: remote_file[C:/Users/User\.chef\local-mode-cache\cache/jdk-7u79-windows-i586.exe] cannot be downloaded from http://download.oracle.com/otn/java/jdk/7u79-b15/jdk-7u79-windows-i586.exe: 401 "Authorization Required"
[2017-05-25T08:30:21+02:00] WARN: remote_file[C:/Users/User\.chef\local-mode-cache\cache/jdk-7u79-windows-i586.exe] cannot be downloaded from http://download.oracle.com/otn/java/jdk/7u79-b15/jdk-7u79-windows-i586.exe: 401 "Authorization Required"


  ================================================================================
  Error executing action `create` on resource 'remote_file[C:/Users/User\.chef\local-mode-cache\cache/jdk-7u79-windows-i586.exe]'
  ================================================================================

  Net::HTTPServerException
  ------------------------
  401 "Authorization Required"

  Resource Declaration:
  ---------------------
  # In C:/Users/User/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/java/recipes/windows.rb

   62:   remote_file cache_file_path do
   63:     checksum pkg_checksum if pkg_checksum
   64:     source node['java']['windows']['url']
   65:     backup false
   66:     action :create
   67:   end
   68: end

  Compiled Resource:
  ------------------
  # Declared in C:/Users/User/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/cookbooks/java/recipes/windows.rb:62:in `from_file'

  remote_file("C:/Users/User\.chef\local-mode-cache\cache/jdk-7u79-windows-i586.exe") do
    provider Chef::Provider::RemoteFile
    action [:create]
    default_guard_interpreter :default
    source ["http://download.oracle.com/otn/java/jdk/7u79-b15/jdk-7u79-windows-i586.exe"]
    use_etag true
    use_last_modified true
    declared_type :remote_file
    cookbook_name "java"
    recipe_name "windows"
    path "C:/Users/User\\.chef\\local-mode-cache\\cache/jdk-7u79-windows-i586.exe"
    checksum nil
    rights nil
    deny_rights nil
    verifications []
  end

  System Info:
  ------------
  chef_version=13.0.118
  platform=windows
  platform_version=6.1.7600
  ruby=ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [i386-mingw32]
  program_name=C:/opscode/chef/bin/chef-client
  executable=C:/opscode/chef/bin/chef-client
```

As you can see in logs above, I've set `['java']['oracle']['accept_oracle_download_terms']` to true (`execute the ruby block Enable Accessing cookies`).

Since this cookbook didn't work for me, I've tried to do my own java cookbook:

```
windows_package package_name do
       source                 source
       action                 :install
       installer_type         :custom
       remote_file_attributes ({
         :headers => {"Cookie" => "oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie"}
      })
      options                 opts
end
```

... and it still gets the same error.

Did anything change on Oracle site that downloading JDK doesn't work anymore? Or do I have to set firewall or something?

Comment: I've heard that Oracle changed something recently, and it could well have broken the automated downloads.   It is unlikely to be a firewall issue.

Comment: I do hope there will be another way to download them then... Do you maybe have source of this information? I would like to read about it.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle introduces changes like this from time to time, that's unfortunately common. Since nothing can be done about it from a regular user's perspective, the best solution is to host the packages yourself, and modify your node attributes to point to that source. That's what I do, with the attributes looking something like this (for linux and a samba share):

```
"java": {
  "install_flavor": "oracle",
  "jdk_version": "8",
  "jdk" : {
    "8" : {
      "x86_64" : {
        "url" : "file:///path/to/jdk-8u131-linux-x64.tar.gz",
        "checksum": "the file's checksum"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This way, changes like the one made by Oracle are no longer problematic.

Comment: I'm trying to write general cookbook for installing Java - I don't have FTP server visible for everyone. Maybe there is some way to get those resources?